# Rails 3 how to prevent redirection when POST is done programatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The controller create method shown below redirects to show method upon successful creation of a customer. I would like this redirection to occur when the post is done from a browser, but the redirection shouldn't happen when I do the post from another program. How do I do that?

```
def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @customer.save
            format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @customer, status: :created, location: @customer }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Send a custom HTTP header from your program to identify it, then check if the header is present, if it is do not redirect, or send a different response.

Comment: I would like to avoid sending custom HTTP header or GET parameter since the post is likely to be done from programs written by other developers. Is there another way?

Comment: Well the other option is to check the user agent, if it's browser use agent then do the redirection, otherise dont.